# Pandas Stacked Bar Plot - Columns by Max Value, Not Summed

Tags: pandas

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_data = np.array([[ 0.110622  ,  0.98174432,  0.56583323],
                    [ 0.61825694,  0.14166864,  0.44180003],
                    [ 0.02572145,  0.55764373,  0.24183103],
                    [ 0.98040318,  0.76171712,  0.41994361],
                    [ 0.49859658,  0.76637672,  0.75487683]])

pd.DataFrame(my_data).plot(kind='bar', stacked='true')
```

Using the above code I get:

[image: plot]

How do I change this so that the hight of every bar is the max value for that bar instead of the sum, and so all the lower values for the bar are in the same bar as different colors?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question, I would normalize your data multiplying each value by the current maximum and then divided by the sum of all elements. So that:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x*df.max(axis=1)/df.sum(axis=1))
```

where:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_data)
```

The new plot is:

```
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked='true')
```

[image]

Hope that helps.